# How to display <div> relative to the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to display  relative to the screen, but not the page. For example, I want to display a window with ads, this window should be centered and on top of other elements, as well as being centered on the screen, regardless of the page's scrolling.

Comment: Take a look at css position fixed for starters

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

Comment: Just set your div to `position: fixed;`. To center set all `position` values to 0 and `margin: auto;`. This will work if your div has some dimensions set. To make sure it is on top just set a `z-index` value higher than the rest of your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, like this:

```js
    $('#center').css("position","absolute");
    $('#center').css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() -     $('#center').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    $('#center').css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $('#center').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
```

```css
div{
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:gray;
         padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="center">Centered content</div>
```